# Deploying SimpleNLG in Android, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nlp, noclassdeffounderror

Building with Eclipse, I'm trying to run [SimpleNLG](http://www.csd.abdn.ac.uk/~ereiter/simplenlg/) in an app; I added the .jar files to the class path, wrote a few lines of code using SimpleNLG classes- this all built fine- but at runtime I get a "NoClassDefFoundError" when a statement in one jar file tries to access org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.class in another .jar. And the class does exist.

At first I suspected this was an issue of converting the .jar files to dalvik, but I'm not receiving any build errors and I am able to run dx on the jar files without issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, I did try the refresh/clean/rebuild cycle...

Comment: I've pretty much given up on this, I only needed a small part of its functionality anyway. If anyone does figure it out though please post an answer.

Comment: You could try to build on the command line with Ant (with a version not smaller than 1.8, I think). And make sure that all the external jars are in the libs-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you compile with different JRE.
check

`javac -version`

you can try:

javac -target 1.6 source 1.6 .....

**OR** 
Perhaps you need to add the Class-Path: in your [manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)